# How to scroll mouse-scroller using selenium C# on a graph?

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, mousewheel

We have test scenario in our application,

> There is a graph on the application when user click and move the mouse
>   scroller up /down it will increase or decrease the size of the graph

We were using Selenium Webdriver-3.141 with C#. We have tried all possible scroll events  (Actions class, JS executor) to scroll the mouse scroller but always it moving whole web page up or down.

Can anyone please suggest how to do only mouse scroller on specifically on a graph.

Thanks
Raghu

Comment: Update the question with the relevant HTML

Answer (score 0):

Currently I do not think interacting with the mouse wheel is supported unfortunately.

Shot in the dark here without the html markup but did you try something like this?

```
var test = Driver.findElement(By.Xpath("//whateverMapIs"));
test.sendKeys(Keys.chord(Keys.Control , Keys.Add));
```

or maybe

```
test.SendKeys(Keys.Control + Keys.Add);
```